# Android setTextViewText not working

Tags: android, android-widget, widget, broadcastreceiver, updates

OK so I have an android widget and I've been having trouble with the android widget updating. I've used some simple hard coded `setTextViewText` but nothing happen when I debug the app..

My code:

```
public class Widget extends AppWidgetProvider {

RemoteViews views;

@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    int N = appWidgetIds.length;
    views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];
        String alarm = Settings.System.getString(context.getContentResolver(),
            Settings.System.NEXT_ALARM_FORMATTED);
        views.setTextViewText(R.id.tvAlarm, alarm);

        views.setTextViewText(R.id.tvNextAlarm, "qwertyuiop");

        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
    }
}
```

I know some of the code is wrong, such as the alarm and I am trying to incorporate a battery status somehow but I've been told that a `BroadcastReceiver` isn't the way forward so at the moment I've commented it out.

But the main problem is the updating the widget to change a `TextView` isn't working...

Answer (score 3):

I've just tried this code in one of my widgets and it works fine:

```
@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {

    // Get ids of all the instances of the widget
    ComponentName widget = new ComponentName(context, MediaWidgerProvider.class);
    int[] widgetIds = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(widget);

    for (int widgetId : widgetIds) {

        RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.my_widget);

        remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.widget_text, "Hello");

        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(widgetId, remoteViews);
    }
}
```